Change colour of line in ggplot2 in R based on a category
i have the following data frame in R
A tibble: 24 × 4
   answers  Year Categories Satisfaction
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 A        2019 Football           46.7
 2 A        2019 Basket             20.7
 3 A        2019 Volley             36.5
 4 A        2020 Football           43.7
 5 A        2020 Basket             21  
 6 A        2020 Volley             31.2
 7 A        2022 Football           49  
 8 A        2022 Basket             17.9
 9 A        2022 Volley             34.2
10 A        2023 Football           33.8

which its structure in R is the following:
df = structure(list(answers = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), Year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023), Categories = c("Football", 
"Basket", "Volley", "Football", "Basket", "Volley", "Football", 
"Basket", "Volley", "Football", "Basket", "Volley", "Tennis", 
"Hockey", "Other", "Tennis", "Hockey", "Other", "Tennis", "Hockey", 
"Other", "Tennis", "Hockey", "Other"), Satisfaction = c(46.7, 
20.7, 36.5, 43.7, 21, 31.2, 49, 17.9, 34.2, 33.8, 30.1, 33.2, 
68.7, 68.7, 68.7, 69.7, 70.2, 70.2, 66.8, 72.7, 72.7, 76.1, 75.4, 
75.4)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

i have grouped the plot using ggplot2 as follows and as the picture shows. But I want to change the colours of the lines.If it the A group the  line to be green and if is group B to be red. How can i do it in R ?
P2 = ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Satisfaction, color = factor(Categories), group = Categories)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = ifelse(answers == "Unfavorable", "darkred", "forestgreen"))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  facet_grid(Categories ~ answers, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Satisfaction",
    color = "Categories") +
  # theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgrey"), # Add background color to facet labels
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"), # Enhance facet label text
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")) + # Increase spacing between facets
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Satisfaction,"%") ), nudge_x = 0.1,color="black")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
P2




Btw, associated topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195231/ggplot2-manually-specifying-colour-with-geom-line

If a legend is not required you can easily achieve your desired result by wrapping the if_else you use to conditionally assign the color in I() aka AsIs which however requires ggplot2 >= 3.5.0. Doing so you can still map a different variable on the color as for your points without the need to specify a separate color scale.
library(ggplot2)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.1'

ggplot(df, aes(
  x = Year, y = Satisfaction,
  color = factor(Categories), group = Categories
)) +
  geom_line(
    aes(color = I(ifelse(answers == "A", "darkred", "forestgreen")))
  ) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  facet_grid(Categories ~ answers, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Satisfaction",
    color = "Categories"
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgrey"),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste(Satisfaction, "%")),
    nudge_x = 0.1, color = "black"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")


UPDATE If you want the same color for the points then I would suggest to globally map answers on the color aes and set the colors using a manual scale as suggested in the answer by @YacineHajji. (Or use aes(color = I(ifelse(answers == "A", "darkred", "forestgreen"))) for the geom_point too). And if your prefer all black points then use geom_point(size = 2, color = "black").
ggplot(df, aes(
  x = Year, y = Satisfaction,
  color = answers
)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(A = "darkred", B = "forestgreen"),
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  facet_grid(Categories ~ answers, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Satisfaction",
    color = "Categories"
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgrey"),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste(Satisfaction, "%")),
    nudge_x = 0.1, color = "black"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")



awesome Stefan.very good solution.Clear explanation. Question: Why it appear these colourful dots. How can i change them to appear in black or in the color of the line ?

You get the colored points as you map Categories on the color aes. See my update to fix that.

You can specify the variable you want the color to depend on in geom_line, here "answers".
Then you specify a scale_colour_manual defining your colors depending on your "answers" group values, here A or B.
ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Satisfaction, color = factor(Categories), group = Categories)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=answers)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(A="darkred", B="forestgreen"))+
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  facet_grid(Categories ~ answers, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Satisfaction",
    color = "Categories") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgrey"), # Add background color to facet labels
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"), # Enhance facet label text
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")) + # Increase spacing between facets
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Satisfaction,"%") ), nudge_x = 0.1,color="black")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")


